# Python unresolved import flask_login

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-dance

I have a Flask web app with flask dance installed. I am trying to set up a logout code section using this example:

```
from flask_login import logout_user
# other imports as necessary

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(somewhere)
```

When I verify my code it says flask_login is unresolved import. So I did a pip install of flask_login. This resulted strangely in importing a package called flask-login (note the different name)

```
(.venv) PS C:\users\jmatson\source\repos\flask_db> pip install flask_login
Collecting flask_login
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/ff/bd9a4d2d81bf0c07d9e53e8cd3d675c56553719bbefd372df69bf1b3c1e4/Flask-Login-0.4.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\users\jmatson\source\repos\flask_db\.venv\lib\site-packages (from flask_login) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\jmatson\source\repos\flask_db\.venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask_login) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\jmatson\source\repos\flask_db\.venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask_login) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\jmatson\source\repos\flask_db\.venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask_login) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\jmatson\source\repos\flask_db\.venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask_login) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\jmatson\source\repos\flask_db\.venv\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->flask_login) (1.1.1)
Installing collected packages: flask-login
  Running setup.py install for flask-login ... done
Successfully installed flask-login-0.4.1
```

This didn't resolve the issue. I tried renaming my import to flask-login, e.g.

```
from flask-login import logout_user
```

However then I get 'undefined variable login'.

I'm a bit stuck here. I need to access this logout_user() method.

Comment: Did you verify that the `Flask-Login` extension was created and initialized right after the application instance by import the `LoginManager` ?

Comment: I have tried adding those values following https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but it makes no difference to the errors around unresolved import.